# vector<char> to string segmentation fault

Tags: c++

trying to initialize a string from a vector. I am supposed to get "hey" as the output. but I got "segmentation fault". what did I do wrong?

```
//write a program that initializes a string from a vector<char>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector<char> cvec;
    cvec[0]='h';
    cvec[1]='e';
    cvec[2]='y';
    string s(cvec.begin(),cvec.end());
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To add to Mysticial's answer - `cvec[0]` (and the other accesses) doesn't invoke a bounds check, and your vector has no elements, so you're accessing some piece of memory that's not allocated to you yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The vector class starts out with a size of zero (by default). So doing that will cause undefined behavior. (in your case, a segmentation fault)

You should use `push_back()` instead:

```
vector<char> cvec;
cvec.push_back('h');
cvec.push_back('e');
cvec.push_back('y');
```

This will append each `char` to the vector.

Comment: thanks, worked. or I have to declare it w/ an initializer. "vector<char> cvec(1);"

Comment: If you use `push_back()`, it's fine the way it is. You don't need an initializer.

Comment: If you want to use the vector as a C-style string, you can add `cvec.push_back(0);` to add the terminating null character.

Answer (score 11):

You need to allocate space in the vector, like this:

```
vector<char> cvec(3);
```

Or push the characters in one by one:

```
vector<char> cvec;
cvec.push_back('h');
cvec.push_back('e');
cvec.push_back('y');
```